# Tricky Double Summation!

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do I show that $$\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{e=1}^{p}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}b_{ke}c_{ei}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{e=1}^{m}\sum_{k=1}^{p}b_{ik}c_{ke}a_{ei}=\sum_{i=1}^{p}\sum_{e=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{m}c_{ik}a_{ke}b_{ei}?$$

I am trying to prove that $tr(ABC)=tr(BCA)=tr(CAB)$, where $A=[a_{ij}]_{m\times n}$, $B=[b_{ij}]_{n\times p}$ and $C=[c_{ij}]_{n\times m}$ and $tr$ is the trace of the matrix.

Comment: All you do is to change the names of the summation variables.

Comment: By the way, these are **triple** summations!

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your first comment.

Comment: In the special case that these matrixes were invertible, you could just use the fact that trace is coordinate independent, and conjugate by the matrix to get the cyclic permutations you want.

Comment: If you know that $tr(XY)=tr(YX)$, then it follows that $tr(ABC)=tr(A(BC))=tr((BC)A)=tr(BCA)$, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, addition is commutative. Finite summation is just a lot of additions.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n} f(i,j) = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{m} f(i,j) $$

Same about multiplication.

Let's us make the notation a bit more orderly, end indices always in order m, p, n (commutation of summation), and relabel the indices: i always to m, e to p, k to n -  $$\sum_{e=1}^{m} f(e) \text{ is the same as} \sum_{i=1}^{m} f(i)$$.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{e=1}^{p}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}b_{ke}c_{ei}= \
\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{e=1}^{p}\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_{ke}c_{ei}a_{ik}= \
\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{i=1}^{p}\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_{ei}a_{ik}b_{ke}$$

and now, reordering the arguments, as multiplication is commutative...

$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{e=1}^{p}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}b_{ke}c_{ei}= \
\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{e=1}^{p}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}b_{ke}c_{ei}= \
\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{i=1}^{p}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}b_{ke}c_{ei}$$

Q.E.D.